# React JS: How can I set state of an array nested in an object nested in an array

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I want to set the state of my component after a certain amount time but the problem is that the state is an array nested in an object nested in an array.
Here is my code:

```
this.state = {
items: {
    label: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    data: [
        {
            label: 'A',
            value: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I want to change the state of `value` to the following:

```
value: ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this like this:

```
this.state.items.data[0].value = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
this.setState({items: this.state.items });
```

If you want something to update which is nested. First update the value directly in the state obj (line 1) and then do setState for the state variable(line2)